# php & mysql while loops

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, while-loop

I'm new in PHP and I think this is an easy question.

I can show the content that comes from my db this way:

```
...
...
 <?php while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($queryNews)){    ?>
  <div class='title_news'><?php echo $row['Title'] ?> </div>
.... and so on...
```

Thats ok so far

Then I want to simulate a kind of pagination: I mean showing as many numbers as news
I first tried a for-loop

```
<?php for($i=1; $i<= sizeof(mysql_fetch_array($queryNews)); $i++){ ?>
    <div class="num_txt"><?php echo $i ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

No success. so I tried an similar  way as the first one, also without success.

```
    <?php 
        $i=1;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryNews)){    ?>
        echo '<script language="javascript">confirm('.$i.')</script>;';
            <div class="num_txt"><?php echo $i ?></div>
   <?php $i++; } ?>
```

Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong??
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop was almost correct, but `sizeof(mysql_fetch_array($queryNews))` fetches a row from the result set and returns the number of columns in that row.  You want the number of rows in the result set:

```
<?php for($i=1, $numRows = mysql_num_rows($queryNews); $i<= $numRows; $i++){ ?>
    <div class="num_txt"><?php echo $i ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `mysql_num_rows` to calculate the total number of rows, or create a variable that increments when you loop through your records to get the total.

Comment: Dont' know why but the block of code that increments weren't showing up..it is now... When you refer to a a variable that increments, is like this way?? Meanwhile I'll trie the mysql_num_rows. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To generate an array of numbers try this:

```
$r = range(mysql_num_rows(YOUR_RESULT_SET));

foreach($r as $n){
echo $n;
}
```

Thats not pagination as most define it, but you can easily search for PHP Pagination if you want to learn how to get groups of, say, 10 results at a time using the LIMIT clause in Mysql.